# JCL SYNCSORT: OMIT and INCLUDE are not interchangeable?

Tags: sorting, include, mainframe, jcl, syncsort

I'm getting different output for these two sort cards, can someone tell me why?

1.

```
INCLUDE COND=((1,3,CH,NE,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,NE,C'PQR'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,NE,C'CAB'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,NE,C'CBA'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,NE,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,NE,C'PQR'))
SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

2.

```
   OMIT COND=((1,3,CH,EQ,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,EQ,C'PQR'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CAB'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CBA'),OR,
              (1,3,CH,EQ,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,EQ,C'PQR'))
SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

This is basically, INCLUDE when NOT-EQUAL and OMIT when EQUAL.

Comment: Something was bugging me. Realised that your first and last conditions are the same. Probably left over from trying to get it to work. So cut the last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have not reversed the **and**'s and **or**'s. This means 
they are very **different** sort tests so will give different answers

If you look at the first Test, in particular:

```
          (1,3,CH,NE,C'CAB'),OR,
          (1,3,CH,NE,C'CBA')
```

Is **always** true,

While the following is **false** when chars 1,3 is **anything** but **CAB** or **CBA**:

```
          (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CAB'),OR,
          (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CBA')
```

with boolean logic, the rules are

```
 not (a and b) = (not A) or (not b)
 not (a or b) = (not A) and (not b)
```

---

So when changing from **omit** to **include**, you must **reverse** the **And** & **or**'s

```
OMIT COND=((1,3,CH,EQ,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,EQ,C'PQR'),OR,
          (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CAB'),OR,
          (1,3,CH,EQ,C'CBA'),OR,
          (1,3,CH,EQ,C'ABC',AND,5,3,CH,EQ,C'PQR'))
SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

becomes:

```
INCLUDE COND=((1,3,CH,NE,C'ABC',or,5,3,CH,NE,C'PQR'),and,
          (1,3,CH,NE,C'CAB'),and,
          (1,3,CH,NE,C'CBA'),and,
          (1,3,CH,NE,C'ABC',or,5,3,CH,NE,C'PQR'))
SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thank you so much. Seems like a silly question now, but I was almost going to believe that INCLUDE and OMIT conditions somehow processed differently! :)